# Animate an image and text in a TabHeader when selected and when mouse is over

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, tabs

I have a tabControl that Contain several TabHeaders,I made it so that the text size of the TabHeader will shrink a little when mouse is over and will become bigger when the TabHeader is selected. I want to add an image into the TabHeader that will act the same way and to act as one item with the text so that both the text and the image will shrink a little when mouse is over and get bigger when TabHeader is selected. Right now both do that but separately meaning that they animate when I hover or click either of them and I want them to act as one

here is the xaml of the TabHeader

```
<TabItem.Header>
  <StackPanel>
     <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <Image Grid.Column="0" x:Name="SalesImg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/Sales.png">
                 <Image.RenderTransform>
                   <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                 </Image.RenderTransform>
                    <Image.Triggers>
                       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
                          <BeginStoryboard>
                            <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                              <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1.5" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1.5" />
                               </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                           </BeginStoryboard>
                         </EventTrigger>
                       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
                         <BeginStoryboard>
                           <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                             <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.2">
                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1" />
                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1" />
                              </Storyboard>
                          </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                      </EventTrigger>
                     </Image.Triggers>
                  </Image>
                 <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Sales" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
               </Grid>
             </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to animate both the image and the text?

Comment: yes at the same time not when I click or hover separately on one of them, because this is the case right now with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the container of the image and text - in this case, a grid - into a [ViewBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx), and animate on the `ViewBox`.

ViewBox takes the all the contents inside it as a single child, so both image and text will grow and shrink in size as a whole.

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <Grid Width="126" Height="48">                       
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.2">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1.5" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1.5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.2">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <Viewbox Width="84" Height="32">
            <Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" CenterX="42" CenterY="16" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
            </Viewbox.RenderTransform>
            <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" x:Name="SalesImg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Source="Images/Sales.png"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Sales" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</TabItem.Header>
```